# Does the magnetic field created by a current carrying coil exert a force on the coil itself?

Tags: electromagnetism

Consider a coil of wire with current flowing through it. Does the magnetic field created by this exert forces on the wire resulting in each part of the wire being pushed inward and outward?

If that is the case, then what about on a straight wire? Is it because of Ampere's law that B is zero because the distance in this case is zero?

Comment: 1) What do you mean by "each part of the wire being pushed inward and outward".

Comment: I mean forces acting at each point along the wire acting towards the center of the loop in the coil. I meant to say inward or outward, sorry.

Comment: 2)  What do you mean by  "the distance in this case is zero"?

Comment: Using Ampere's Law the formula for the magnetic field are a current carrying wire is B=μ0I/2πr, where r is the distance between the wire and the point we are examining. In this case r = 0 because we are examining the location the wire is at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First case, a coil: yes, it does. Parts of the coil create a magnetic field at the location of currents in other parts of the coil, hence there’s a force. For a strong coil, the forces can be very large.

But the long, straight wire is a special case. The current in the wire, any bit of it, generates a zero field at any point on the wire. So there’s no net force.

Comment: Thank you so much! Because current can flow clockwise and counterclockwise and still produce a field in the same direction, what decides if the forces are directed inward or outward?

Comment: Not sure what you mean about direction.  Could you clarify please?  The force on a coil (solenoid) is radially outward lots, and axially extending a little. You can see this by picking on quarter-loop of a coil and using the right hand rule to find the field direction on another quarter turn, then the right hand rule again to find the force direction.

Comment: I made a mistake, when I said "current can flow clockwise or counterclockwise and still produce a field in the same direction". The direction of the flow of current is actually what simulates the north and south poles of a bar magnet.

Comment: So the force is always radially outward? I think I understand, it's because when the direction of current changes so does the direction of the created magnetic field which keeps the same direction in the right hand rule no matter the direction of current flow

Comment: @Jody4422 Right! That’s a good way to think it through.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it is easiest to figure out the force directions on charges in magnetic fields by looking at the magnetic flux density around a particular charge. The force as best I can tell always points from high flux density to low flux density regardless of whether the charge is positive or negative. It can be used to determine the lorentz force direction (I believe) as long as you examine the distortion of the external magnetic field about a charge caused by its own magnetic field from motion. So in the case of a loop the flux density is highest inside the loop so the force is outward.